# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and this is my first project. I have page for survey where there is option for uploading photo. 
When I select the photo from gallery I am getting error. The error seems to be on the lines  `753: String[] strArray = str.split(",");`  and on `554: String[] strArray = str.split(",");` 
I had to remove lots of portion of code because of posting limit.

PublicSurvay.java:

```
public class PublicSurvay extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, LocationListener {

    CheckBox c1, c2, c3, c4_sign;
    String URLDATA, URLNEWDATA;
    Location location;
    LocationManager manager;
    double l1 = 0, l2 = 0, l3 = 0, l4 = 0, l5 = 0, l6 = 0;
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btn_upload1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PublicSurvay.this).setTitle("Select picture").setMessage("Choose Any one")
                        .setPositiveButton("Choose From Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Choose From Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });
        btn_upload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(PublicSurvay.this).setTitle("Select picture").setMessage("Choose Any one")
                        .setPositiveButton("Choose From Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(i, 200);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Choose From Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 102);
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });
        btn_upload3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PublicSurvay.this).setTitle("Select picture").setMessage("Choose Any one")
                        .setPositiveButton("Choose From Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(i, 300);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Choose From Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 103);

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });
        try {
            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location == null) {
                location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                l1 = location.getLatitude();
                l2 = location.getLongitude();
            } else {
                l1 = location.getLatitude();
                l2 = location.getLongitude();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PublicSurvay.this, "", "Sending data...", true);
                    URLDATA = "http://www.avj.890m.com/publicservay.php?uname=" + uname + "&email=" + email + "&address=" + address + "&tro_milk=" + tropical1 + "&c1=" + c_1 + "&c2=" + c_2 + "&c3=" + c_3 + "&plumeria=" + palumaria + "&terms=" + c_4 + "&lat=" + l1 + "&log1=" + l2 + "&l3=" + l3 + "&l4=" + l4 + "&l5=" + l5 + "&l6=" + l6;
                    URLDATA = URLDATA.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    Log.e("URLDATA", URLDATA);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            uploadFile1(uname, email, address, tropical1, c_1, c_2, c_3, palumaria, c_4, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6);
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PublicSurvay.this, "", "Sending data...", true);
                    URLDATA = "http://www.avj.890m.com/publicservay.php?uname=" + uname + "&email=" + email + "&address=" + address + "&tro_milk=" + tropical1 + "&img_tro_milk=" + img1 + "&c1=" + c_1 + "&c2=" + c_2 + "&c3=" + c_3 + "&img_milk_spec=" + img2 + "&plumeria=" + palumaria + "&img_pulmeria=" + img3 + "&terms=" + c_4 + "&lat=" + l1 + "&log1=" + l2 + "&l3=" + l3 + "&l4=" + l4 + "&l5=" + l5 + "&l6=" + l6;
                    URLDATA = URLDATA.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    Log.e("URLDATA", URLDATA);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            uploadFile(uname, email, address, tropical1, img1, c_1, c_2, c_3, img2, palumaria, img3, c_4, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (compoundButton == c1) {
            if (!b) {


            } else {
                c_1 = "true";
            }
        }
        if (compoundButton == c2) {
            if (!b) {


            } else {
                c_2 = "true";
            }


        }
        if (compoundButton == c3) {
            if (!b) {

            } else {
                c_3 = "true";
            }
        }
        if (compoundButton == c4_sign) {
            if (!b) {


            } else {
                c_4 = "true";
            }

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        l1 = location.getLatitude();
        l2 = location.getLongitude();
    }


    public int uploadFile(String uname, String email, String addressdata, String tropiw, String sourceFileUri, String
            c1, String c2, String c3, String img11, String palumaria, String img22, String terms, double lat, double log1, double l3, double l4, double l5, double l6) {
        try {

            String fileName = sourceFileUri;
            String fileName1 = img11;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, bytesAvailable1, bufferSize1, bytesRead1;
            byte[] buffer;
            byte[] buffer1;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                dialog.dismiss();



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /// messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                    }
                });
                return 0;
            } else {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);


                    URL url = new URL(URLDATA);


                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uname", uname);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("email", email);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("address", addressdata);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("tro_milk", tropiw);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("c1", c1);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("c2", c2);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("c3", c3);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("img_milk_spec", img11);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("plumeria", palumaria);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("img_pulmeria", img22);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("terms", terms);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("log1", String.valueOf(log1));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("l3", String.valueOf(l3));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("l4", String.valueOf(l4));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("l5", String.valueOf(l5));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("l6", String.valueOf(l6));
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                    // create a buffer of  maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();


                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    }

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                            + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                        + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                                Toast.makeText(PublicSurvay.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(PublicSurvay.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(PublicSurvay.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();


            } // End else block
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Upload Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return serverResponseCode;
    }

    public int uploadFile1(String uname, String email, String addressdata, String tropiw, String c1, String c2, String c3, String palumaria, String terms, double lat, double log1, double l3, double l4, double l5, double l6) {
        try {


            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, bytesAvailable1, bufferSize1, bytesRead1;
            byte[] buffer;
            byte[] buffer1;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            try {

                // FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);


                URL url = new URL(URLDATA);


                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                conn.setRequestProperty("uname", uname);
                conn.setRequestProperty("email", email);
                conn.setRequestProperty("address", addressdata);
                conn.setRequestProperty("tro_milk", tropiw);

                conn.setRequestProperty("c1", c1);
                conn.setRequestProperty("c2", c2);
                conn.setRequestProperty("c3", c3);
                conn.setRequestProperty("plumeria", palumaria);
                conn.setRequestProperty("terms", terms);
                conn.setRequestProperty("l3", String.valueOf(l3));
                conn.setRequestProperty("l4", String.valueOf(l4));
                conn.setRequestProperty("l5", String.valueOf(l5));
                conn.setRequestProperty("l6", String.valueOf(l6));

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);





                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();





            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(PublicSurvay.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(PublicSurvay.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return serverResponseCode;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            img1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img1);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l1 = CountData(lat_data);
                l2 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
        if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            img2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img2);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l3 = CountData(lat_data);
                l4 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (requestCode == 300 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            img3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img3);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l5 = CountData(lat_data);
                l6 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToLast();

            img1 = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img1);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l1 = CountData(lat_data);
                l2 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (requestCode == 102 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToLast();

            img2 = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img2);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l3 = CountData(lat_data);
                l4 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (requestCode == 103 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToLast();

            img3 = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(img3);

                String lat = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE;
                String lat_data = exif.getAttribute(lat);

                String log = ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE;
                String log_data = exif.getAttribute(log);

                cursor.close();
                l5 = CountData(lat_data);
                l6 = CountLongitude(log_data);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cursor.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public double CountData(String str) {

        String[] strArray = str.split(",");

        String str1 = strArray[0];
        String[] s1 = str1.split("/");
        String a1 = s1[0];
        String a2 = s1[1];
        int a11 = Integer.parseInt(a1);
        int a22 = Integer.parseInt(a2);

        System.out.println(a11 + "" + a22);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `CountData()` with a null argument somewhere. You'll need to debug to figure where and why. You should also look into how to create a [mcve]. Surely not all of that code is causing your issue.

Comment: It seems the message is clear: you're trying to split on a null string object, some how, some way. Since there are no line numbers in the code example, the only one str.split() call that appears is in function `CountData`. You'll have to add some debugging to see how you're getting null strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to check for null in Android. Please add a null check in your method until you figure out why you get `str` as null.

```
 public double CountData(String str) {
     double result = 0; 
     if(str != null) {       
        String str1 = strArray[0];
        String[] s1 = str1.split("/");
        String a1 = s1[0];
        String a2 = s1[1];
        int a11 = Integer.parseInt(a1);
        int a22 = Integer.parseInt(a2);

        System.out.println(a11 + "" + a22);
        //assign some value to result 
     }
     return result;
}
```